# What is the best solution to host PFsense and NAS on the same hardware?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, nas, freebsd, pfsense

These are my first steps in virtualization and things may not be as easy as they seem.

Simply put, I have a 4-core CPU and I would like to host both PFsense and FreeNas (or any other NAS solution), each of them using 2 physical cores.

I thought I would simply run PFfsense as the main OS then run VirtualBox to virtualize FreeNAS.

However, it seems that it is not as easy because PFsense is a highly tuned FreeBSD distribution and I cannot seem to be able to install packages that are not meant to be used with PFsense.

Any recommendations ?

Hardware : 
Intel Pentium J5005,
8 GB of RAM,
64 GB storage
Dual Wan (main reason to use PFsense)

Comment: Depending on your hardware, beyond the CPU, VMware ESXi is probably a better bet since it's a type 1 hypervisor.  I know PFSense will run as a VM under VMware's products (https://www.netgate.com/docs/pfsense/virtualization/virtualizing-pfsense-with-vmware-vsphere-esxi.html).

Comment: ESXi sounds like the good option ! What do you mean by "Depending on your hardware" ? My hardware is detailed in my first post. Thant you !

Comment: You don't list NICs, motherboard, drive controllers, etc.  Those are important for ESXi.  6.7 has gotten more restrictive than previous versions, which is why I mention checking the HCL...or just give it a try installing and see what happens.  6.5 might be a better fit if you're not using name-brand server hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to instead virtualise PFsense and pass through your network connection to there if necessary. If FreeNAS can support virtualisation software, this may be one of your only suitable solutions. Another solution could be to use a very very lightweight Linux distribution and virtualise both FreeNAS and pfsense - this way you can set them up as separate entities and rebooting neither freeNas nor pfsense machines will reboot the other. For this you may want a stable distro like Debian but I have not used it so I cannot comment from experience, though Debian is known for its stability.